# How do I use my microSD card again after formatting in an unknown format accidentally, and it is no longer recognized?

Tags: formatting

I was trying to setup an [Ubuntu Remix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Netbook_Edition) boot-up drive on my 4 GB [microSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Physical_size) card and accidentally formatted the card in some unknown format.

1. Is there a way to determine what format I actually did format it into?
2. Is there a way to re-format the card so I can use it again? Right now Ubuntu and [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) won't even recognize the card at all ... I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: When you say that they won't recognize the card at all, do you mean that they won't mount it, or that they don't even appear in /dev/? I'd get a partitioning tool (GPartEd is my favorite on Linux) and take a look at the card. Does it appear in the device list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) first. It should show the device, as long as the card is plugged in. If not, the long way around it is:

1. **Take care at each step below. If you choose the wrong device in step 5, you will destroy all data on that device upon repartition/format**
2. Open up a shell (Terminal) window.
3. Execute `sudo fdisk -l` (will ask for your acct password) and take note of the output, seeing which disk entries are listed (like `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc.).
4. Plug in your card and re-run `sudo fdisk -l` to see the list of devices. There should be a new one in the list. Let's say it's `/dev/SD` for example, but substitute accordingly.
5. Execute `sudo fdisk /dev/SD`
6. Hit `p` to see how many partitions are on the device, then `d` with the appropriate number to delete all of them.
7. Hit `n` and create a new `primary` partition. If you now hit `p` you should see it in the list. Hit `w` to write the new partition table to disk.
8. Format the new partition with `mkfs.ext2 /dev/SD1`
9. It should now show up.

Comment: Thanks, I don't care about any data on the drive. I'm looking to just put the Ubuntu Remix install bootup file on there. I'll try this out.

Comment: Glad to have helped =)